# "Cannot get /" - 404

Tags: svelte

Going through the quick start [docs](https://svelte.dev/blog/the-easiest-way-to-get-started#2_Use_degit) for Svelte, ran the commands to get started.

```
npx degit sveltejs/template my-svelte-project
cd my-svelte-project
npm install
npm run dev
```

Result: `Your application is ready~!`

Open up `localhost:5000`: "Cannot get /"

Tried a couple different ways, same thing each time.

I'm using Chrome v84, macOS Mojave v10.14, latest Svelte version and Rollup.

CLI logs:

[image: CLI logs]

Anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

**UPDATE**

Tried using the Svelte REPL to download the zip file but this gives me the same error.

Here's my file structure if anyone is able to compare:

```
|-node_modules
|-public
  |-build
    |-bundle.css
    |-bundle.js
    |-bundle.css.map
    |-bundle.js.map
  |-favicon.png
  |-global.css
  |-index.html
|-scripts
  |-setupTypeScript.js
|-src
  |-App.svelte
  |-main.js
|-.gitignore
|-package.json
|-package-lock.json
|-README.md
|-rollup.config.js
```

Maybe I'm missing a file or something? No idea.

Comment: It looks alright to me and works with those exact commands on my machine (with Ubuntu though). Do you see the request in the console? (Normally it would look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UR4yv.png) - do you see a 404 there too or no request at all?) Is there maybe something else listening on port 5000 already? Does `npm run build` produce any errors (it should end with `created public/build/bundle.js`)?

Comment: There are no logs in the vscode console, in the dev tools I get `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Nothing else on port 5000

Comment: i just tried the same steps and i didn't get any problems. Perhaps you need to update your node.version? In my case I noticed that i get ([2020-07-25 10:12:45] waiting for changes...) and I get (created public\build\bundle.js in 402ms) before (your application is ready) which i don't see in your screenshot so that gives me an indication that this is related to your node.js

Comment: Updated node but still getting the same issue. If I save App.svelte I get this: `bundles src/main.js → public/build/bundle.js...
created public/build/bundle.js in 66ms`

Comment: does it work when you go to `localhost:5000/index.html` ? on some systems there is an issue with the `/` not being routed correctly

Comment: It just says "Cannot get /index.html"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'sort of' fix I found is to comment out the line `!production && livereload('public'),` in rollup.config.js, whilst it's running on port 5000. It then switches to a random port and works fine.

**UPDATE**

An actual fix (in the CLI):

```
lsof -i :5000
```

Grab the `PID` and `kill`:

```
kill -9 35587
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `index.html` file, within your link tags that refer to your `bundle.css` and `bundle.js`, make sure your hrefs refer you to `build/bundle.css` and `build/bundle.js` (or wherever those files are actually located).